# Alternatives to "knowledge" and "gnosis" for words meaning "science" but with Germanic or Greek roots?

Tags: synonyms, old-english, greek

What are the closest synonyms for *science* with Germanic or Greek roots?
*Knowledge* (Germanic) seems too shallow, and *gnosis* (Greek) too mystical.

Comment: I've voted to close this question because I don't understand how we are supposed to know what you will consider an appropriate level of shallowness or mysticality. You can improve this question by adding more description of your requirements for these roots, such as giving an example of what you actually need them for. Otherwise, it's just a matter of opinion.

Comment: @sumelic - Are you meaning to be humorous? If you come up with a Greek-root synonym that you think is less mystical than *gnosis*, you'll find out whether you get a green tick or not.

Comment: I liked the original question, which was "What are the closest synonyms for *science* with Germanic or Greek roots? *Knowledge* (Germanic) seems too shallow, and *gnosis* (Greek) too mystical."

Comment: Anglish uses "ken".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Consider [***episteme***](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Episteme):

> Episteme means knowledge, as in "justified true belief" in the terminology of the philosopher Plato. It is etymologically derived from the Ancient Greek word ἐπιστήμη for knowledge or science, which comes from the verb ἐπίσταμαι, "to know". Episteme as knowledge contrasts doxa, Plato's term for common belief or opinion. Episteme is distinguished from techne, which is knowledge in an applied way as in a craft. The word epistemology means the study of knowledge, and is derived from episteme.

[Wikipedia]

Comment: Many thanks - that's an excellent answer. I'll wait for whether someone comes up with a Germanic-root word before accepting.